# Selenium IDE and xpath - find text / row in table and select radio box

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

I've been using Selenium IDE and getting some good results. I've done a lot of reading about following-sibling and preceding-sibling but I can't locate the right radio button.

Essentially I want to find the row in a table with the word 'testing' and then click the radio button in the  cell.

So far I can find the input button 
    //input[@type='radio']

and find the text testing
    //a[contains(text(),'testing')]

I've been trying to use this in the ide

```
check | //input[@type='radio']/following-sibling::td[1]/a[contains(text(),'testing')]
```

but I get the error `[error] locator not found: //input[@type='radio']/following-sibling::a[contains(text()[1],'testing')]`

Any help to change this is really appreciated :)

Cheers

Damien

here's the bare basic table ...

```
<tbody id="list">
<tr>
<th>
<label class="radio">
<input class="presentation_radio" type="radio" value="1" name="presentation_radio">
</label>
</th>
<td>
<a href="/link_to/document">testing </a>
</td>
<td>testing</td>
<td>Joe Acme</td>
<td>Presentation</td>
<td>03 May 2012</td>
<td>5 (1)</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your xpath is that `td` and `input` are not **sibling** (they don't have common parent) and even if you change your xpath to more correct version:

```
//input[@type='radio']/following::td[1]/a[contains(text(),'testing')]
```

it will find `a` that have preceding checkbox instead of checkbox itself. So correct xpath will be:

```
//a[contains(text(),'testing')]/preceding::input[@type='radio'][1]
```

or

```
//tr[descendant::a[contains(.,'testing')]]//input[@type='radio']
```

For xpath axis tutorial read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456.aspx

Comment: Where is CSS mentioned in this question?

Comment: Hey thanks for this ... this one works `//a[contains(text(),'testing')]/preceding::input[@type='radio']`

Comment: @Damien sorry, it should be with `[1]` in the end. See my corrected answer.

Comment: @AlehDouhi Yes i see ... it always selects the `th` in row 1 otherwise