# Selenium target of radio input based on higher level label

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

Basically I have more than one yes/no radio combination that I need to distinguish between. There are two label levels - so I have to put both in the Target expression to pick the correct value.

HTML

```
<div id="divFld1279-32-6093" class="wdg">
<label title="Whether a client is currently attending secondary school" for="Fld1279-32-6093">
    At School Flag
    <span class="spc"></span>
</label>
<br></br>
<div class="rbCv">
    <label class="rbRad">
        <input class="wdg" type="radio" value="Y" name="Fld1279-32-6093"></input>
       Yes
    </label>
</div
```

Attempts to date

This works if there is only one yes/no radio selection:

```
//label[contains(text(),'Yes')]//input[@type="radio"]
```

This does not work:

```
//label[contains(text(), 'At School Flag')]/preceding::label[contains(text(),'Yes')]//input[@type="radio"]
```

Research to date

I tried to use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428878/selenium-ide-and-xpath-find-text-row-in-table-and-select-radio-box) to come up with a solution but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of minimal changes to your attempt, replace `preceding` with `following` because the `<label>` containing text `"Yes"` is *following* the `<div>` containing text `"At School Flag"`.

Then instead of `text()` use simple `.`. Using `text()` only works if the text node to be evaluated is the *first child* of the element. As a more general rule, if you don't have to use `text()` or if you are not sure whether to use `text()` or `.`, go with the latter, **use `.`** (wrapped for readability) :

```
//label[contains(., 'At School Flag')]
 /following::label[contains(.,'Yes')]
  //input[@type="radio"]
```

Comment: Thanks @har07 very useful - both the solution and tips. Much appreciated.